# Document JavaScript with optional first parameter

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

I'm trying to document one of those annoying functions which has an optional *first* parameter in JavaScript.

Something like the function `.use()` from `express`

```
function use(path, callback) // path is optional
```

I'm trying to find something that works, and ideally isn't terribly ugly.

My preference for the actual code signature would be this:

```
function use(...args) {
  const [callback, path] = args.reverse();
}
```

In that case, I don't have two parameters, so if I try to use two `@param` lines, I get yelled at in the JSDoc block:

```
/**
 * @param {String=} path
 * @param {Function} callback
 */
function use(...args) // mismatched parameters
```

If I use the parameters as intended and use a different pattern for putting the parameters in place, I get yelled at (by WebStorm) because `callback` isn't a `String`:

```
/**
 * @param {String=} path
 * @param {Function} callback
 */
function use(path, callback) {
  if (typeof path == 'function') {
    callback = path; // yelled at because callback can't be a string
    path = undefined;
  }
}
```

I've googled around and found lots of older stuff with different people debating this problem, but no clear answers. Since the posts are older and a lot has happened, I wanted to ask anew: Is there a way to document this so everything is happy (at least in WebStorm), or is there some new ES# syntax that allows for optional first parameters (that can generate proper auto-complete)?

Comment: This is where you switch to flow or typescript ;)

Comment: Or just start kicking people in the shins when they use this goofy reverse optional parameters pattern. I love vanilla JS, but whoever first popularized this pattern is... not my favorite person. =p

Comment: On a semi-related note: you might want to look into the `@callback` tag - http://usejsdoc.org/tags-callback.html

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I know about `@callback`. I just used `Function` for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 1):

```
@param {(String=|Function=)} path
```

is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm aware of this one, and it may be the closest I can get... but it's just oh so ugly. I then have to explain that "if it's a function, it's actually the callback".

Comment: Yeah, hence the `@callback`, makes stuff a tiny bit more explicit. Also, marking the second parameter as optional as well would probably provide a bit of a hint. I completely agree on the entire thing being super moronic though.